# Binding to a drawingVisual element

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I set binding for a dependency property which belongs to DrawingVisual element in code ?

For any dependency property that belongs FrameworkElement I have called elem.SetBinding(...) but I do not have this function in DrawingVisual class.

Comment: Could you explain a bit better?

Comment: explained more detailed

Answer (score 0):

The FrameworkElement class and the FrameworkContentElement class both expose a SetBinding method. As the DrawingVisual does not inherit from either of these it does not have this method.

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx):

> DrawingVisual is a lightweight drawing class that is used to render
>   shapes, images, or text. This class is considered lightweight because
>   it does not provide layout, input, focus, or event handling, which
>   improves its performance. For this reason, drawings are ideal for
>   backgrounds and clip art.

So it is intentionally (no event handling), to keep it very fast.

Comment: The fact that they do not expose that method is irrelevant though. Any `DependencyObject` can have dependency properties, they need to be bound differently though using [`BindingOperations.SetBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding.aspx). `DrawingVisual` just does not have any DPs.